# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'u675813745_ymeda'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

here The laravel refers to the reference in config/database.php which was set the to the database 'u675813745_ymeda'. So i changed the database and other credentials to the database i am using. and everything in the "env" file is good.

Here is the code of Database.php inside the config folder

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'sonder'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

here is the code of **env** file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sonder
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Previously in the database.php file the database was set to 'u675813745_ymeda' and i changed it. Looks like database.php is overriding the .env file. So i changed in both. But still it throws the same error 
and yes i Have cleared the cache using **php artisan cache:clear**

Comment: In your root directory, `grep -R u675813745_ymeda *`. See if it's in any other files.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem a couple of weeks ago, mine was caused by a queue that kept the old config going, restarting that queue solved it for me.